# Specifying color and legend for R bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating bar charts to present some precipitation data. I'm having an issue since I would like to have a legend beside the chart, while also having the bars be blue, but it seems like I cannot have both based on the code I have tried. Any guidance for what I could try would be much appreciated!

In this code, I manage to get a legend beside the bar chart, but the bars are not blue:

```
generate_precipitation_chart <- function(precip_data, chart_title) {
  precipitation_chart <- ggplot(data = precip_data, aes(x = Timestamp, y = `Total Precipitation (mm)`, fill = "Precipitation")) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    labs(title = chart_title, y = "Total Precipitation (mm)", x = "Timestamp") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "right")  
    
  return(precipitation_chart)
}
```

[image]

In this code, the bars are blue, but there is no legend:

```
generate_precipitation_chart <- function(precip_data, chart_title) {
  precipitation_chart <- ggplot(data = precip_data, aes(x = Timestamp, y = `Total Precipitation (mm)`, fill = "Precipitation")) +
    geom_bar(fill = 'blue', stat = "identity") +
    labs(title = chart_title, y = "Total Precipitation (mm)", x = "Timestamp") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "right")  
  
  return(precipitation_chart)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Legends in ggplot2 are generated when you map a variable to an aesthetic using `aes()`. To manually specify what values should get what fill colors, use also `scale_fill_manual()`.

Comment: Hi Jon, that works great now that I incorporated that! The code that I used `generate_precipitation_chart <- function(precip_data, chart_title) {
  precipitation_chart <- ggplot(data = precip_data, aes(x = Timestamp, y = 'Total Precipitation (mm)', fill = "Precipitation")) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Precipitation" = "blue")) +  
    labs(title = chart_title, y = "Total Precipitation (mm)", x = "Timestamp") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "right")  
  
  return(precipitation_chart)
}`